# No record found in lookup

Tags: salesforce-classic

I have created master details field in custom object. The field name called Account. When I click the icon it shows no record found. But in my account object have more than 20 records.

Comment: The items shown immediately after clicking the lookup are only the ones you have recently searched for. Did you actually type a search term in the search box and click go?

Comment: Yes, I tried it too. Its showing same no record found

Comment: Make sure that you have accurate permissions to the records

Answer (score 1):

Check whether there is some custom search filter written possibly for searching out Accounts with different record types.

Answer (score 0):

Check the OWD is not set to private, and if so, what sharing rules are defined. This will happen if you don't have access to any of the records. Also you must enter a search string for the lookup.